# Can you build a CORS-proxy inside a service-worker?

Tags: cors, service-worker

Can a `service-worker` strip CORS headers to defeat cross-origin issues?

I understand there's two ways to do this normally:

1. control the server and set the headers as you like
2. use a CORS-proxy

But, can you build a CORS-proxy inside a service-worker?

Comment: No, you can’t build a CORS proxy inside a service worker. Service workers are frontend code running at a particular origin and are restricted by the same-origin exactly in the same way as any other frontend code. If you could get around the same-origin policy just be creating a service worker, the same-origin policy would be useless as a security measure.

Comment: CORS proxies don’t work by stripping headers — instead they work by adding headers to responses. And adding CORS headers to a response the browser has already received won’t cause browsers to relax the same-origin policy. Browsers already knows whether the response has the necessary CORS headers. What you _can_ do with a service worker is, you can add headers to a _request_ — for example, you can add the Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy and Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy headers to a request. But neither those nor any other headers you add to a request will cause the same-origin policy to be relaxed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the comments :

CORS proxies don’t work by stripping headers — instead they work by adding headers to responses. And adding CORS headers to a response the browser has already received won’t cause browsers to relax the same-origin policy. Browsers already knows whether the response has the necessary CORS headers. What you can do with a service worker is, you can add headers to a request — for example, you can add the Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy and Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy headers to a request. But neither those nor any other headers you add to a request will cause the same-origin policy to be relaxed. –